# Handling unexisting actions?

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is the best way to handle unexisting actions in the Zend Framework?

Depending on the controller I want to be able handle the request differently.

BR
Niklas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to your controller class

```
public function __call($method, $args){

    if ('Action' == substr($method, -6) && $method != 'indexAction') {
        // If the action method was not found, forward to the index action
        return $this->_forward('index');
    }

    // all other methods throw an exception
    throw new Exception('Invalid method "' . $method . '" called', 500);
}
```

In this case missing actions will be forwarded to the index action

Answer (score 0):

This is explained at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.action.html#zend.controller.action.subclassing.example-call